# Divide elements within multidimensional array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, formula, division

I am working with 1 array that has 2 elements (new int [10][2] to be specific) and I can't figure out how to get column 0 to be divided column 1 for each row.

For instance: row 5 c0[20]c1[2] = should be interpreted by the program as 20÷2 and then output the answer as 10 for each row. My program currently isn't doing that. Where am I going wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class 2darraydivision {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = getArray();
        System.out.print("");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("\nStudent %d needs ", i + 1);
            System.out.printf(sum(a) + " terms to graduate.");
        }
        System.out.println("\n\nData captured from user:");
        for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < a[row].length; column++) {
                System.out.print(a[row][column] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int[][] getArray() {
        int[][] b = new int[10][2];
        java.util.Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter classes remaining and taking each term for...\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Student %d: ", i + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
                b[i][j] = input.nextInt();
                if ((b[j][0] < 1) || (b[j][0] > 20)) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter number of courses remaining between 1 and 20.");
                } else if ((b[j][1] < 1) || (b[j][1] > 5)) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter number of courses taking between 1 and 5.");
                }
            }
        }
        input.close();
        return b;
    }

    public static int sum(int[][] b) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[j].length; j++) {
                total = b[j][0] / b[j][1];
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question does not show input data (like `20` and `2`). (And your `sum()` neither computes a sum, nor can I see it updating a total.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say:

> how to get column 0 to be divided column 1 for each row

And you say:

> output the answer as 10 for each row

Seem your method `sum` is your attempt at doing that, so let's have a look.

```
public static int sum(int[][] b) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b[j].length; j++) {
            total = b[j][0] / b[j][1];
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Problems:

- *"for each row"*

  If you want to process each row, then you need a loop, but you have two nested loops, why?

  Remove the `j` loop.
- *"how to get column 0 to be divided column 1"*

  You're doing it, except replace `j` with `i`, since we just eliminated the `j` loop.

  ```
  int result = b[i][0] / b[i][1];
  ```
- *"output the answer"*

  That would mean to print it, so perhaps a `println` statement would be appropriate.

All-in-all, that means:

```
// Using regular for loop
public static void divideAndPrint(int[][] b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(b[i][0] / b[i][1]);
    }
}
```

```
// Using enhanced for loop
public static void divideAndPrint(int[][] b) {
    for (int[] row : b) {
        System.out.println(row[0] / row[1]);
    }
}
```

```
// Using Java 8+ lambda:
public static void divideAndPrint(int[][] b) {
    Arrays.asList(b).forEach(row -> System.out.println(row[0] / row[1]));
}
```

```
// Using Java 8+ streams:
public static void divideAndPrint(int[][] b) {
    Arrays.stream(b).mapToInt(r -> r[0] / r[1]).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
}
```